# How Can I get individual counts of Group_Concat data in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data something like this,

```
ID - Group_Concat
1 - aa,ab,ac,ad
2 - ab,ad,aa
3 - ad,ab,ac
```

Now I Want to get the result like this:

```
Group_Concat  -  Count
aa           -   2
ab           -  3
ac           -   2
ad           -   3
```

Comment: Can you write the sample data and expected result in proper columns instead?

Comment: If I was going there, I wouldn't start from here :-(

Comment: It's really hard to split a comma-separated string in MySQL. You should normalize the data.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` is a MySQL aggregation function. If possible, find the source of this query to return to the unit level data to retrieve your counts.

Comment: @Parfait I suspect he's not actually using `GROUP_CONCAT()`, he's just using that to describe a column that contains comma-separated data, in the format that `GROUP_CONCAT()` creates.